# Loading Regular and Bold fonts as part of the same font familly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In Fonts I have `RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf` and `RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf` [downloaded](https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/releases/tag/v2.138) in Fonts, and both set to Build as Resources

If user selects that font it will be loaded

```
var ff = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Fonts/"), "./#Roboto Condensed");
```

But this doesn't load the bold version even though it has the same name, so this will not work here, or anywhere else where I try to set FontWeight to Bold (Regular loads fine)

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run >Normal </Run>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold">Bold </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

What am I missing?